# How to use ES6 imports and CommonJS imports in the same file in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, babeljs, es6-modules, commonjs

I came across tutorials on how to use ES6 imports in Node.js using Babel, but then CommonJS imports don't work. I would like to use ES6 imports and CommonJS imports **in the same files** in Node.js (Express.js).

**main.js**

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
import {GotRequestFunction} from 'got';
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Docs:

1. [Differences between ES modules and CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_differences_between_es_modules_and_commonjs)
2. [module.createRequire(filename)](https://nodejs.org/api/module.html#module_module_createrequire_filename)

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

import { A } from "./A.mjs" // NB: .mjs extention
console.log(A) // it works

const fs = require('fs')
console.log(fs) // it works as well
```

If you don't like `.mjs` extension, then follow this advice given by the the node executable itself.

```
`Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.`
```

Comment: Using require from createRequire  and an .mjs extension works.

Comment: es6 import from commonjs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70396888/1764521