# How to use ES6 modules in CommonJS?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I've seen
[Importing ES6 modules in CommonJS Node app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67137415/importing-es6-modules-in-commonjs-node-app)
[How to use ES6 modules with commonjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68277704/how-to-use-es6-modules-with-commonjs)
and https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling

And I still don't get it. Fairly new to javascript.

The fundamental question is "What do I need to do and where do the bits go that enable me to use ES6 modules inside CommonJS?

Comment: Today, it is possible to import ES6 modules into CommonJS modules using [dynamic imports](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-expressions). The most upvoted question below explains it well!

Comment: I just found this great guide from Sindre Sorhus: https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c

Answer (score 29):

In Node.js, if you want to import an ES module in a CommonJS module you can use dynamic `import` and the *.mjs* file extension on the ES modules. For example:

*index.js* CommonJS

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');  // to show this is a commonJS module

import('./path/to/mod.mjs').then(mod =>
  console.log(mod.msg);    //  "Hello world!"
);
```

*mod.mjs* ES module

```
export const msg = "Hello world!";
```

---

Two examples of how `import` could be used within a CommonJS module to import all or some of the `lodash-es` package:

```js
import('lodash-es').then(_ => {
  console.log(_.pad(_.toUpper('hello world'), 17, '*'));
});
```

```js
Promise.all([
  import('lodash-es/pad.js'),
  import('lodash-es/toUpper.js'),
])
.then(([{ default: pad }, { default: toUpper }]) => {
  console.log(pad(toUpper('hello world'), 17, '#'));
});
```

Or you can just import what you need into a different CommonJS module then export a `Promise` which you can then `import` or `require`.

*utils.js*

```js
module.exports = Promise.all([
  import('lodash-es/pad.js'),
  import('lodash-es/toUpper.js'),
]);
```

*index.js*

```js
require('./utils.js').then(([{ default: pad }, { default: toUpper }]) => {
  console.log(pad(toUpper('hello world'), 17, '*'));
});
```

Comment: Great answer! Does this need some sort of configuration unmentioned here (similar to `"type": "module"` in package.json for ESModule packages)?

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky No, it doesn't. The file extensions describe the module type of each file instead.

Comment: Note that the string passed to `import` does not have to be a relative path, it can also be the name of a package in a *node_modules* folder.

Comment: Ok, this is a help. How can I use this to import an ES6 package, like `loadash-es`? Is it a case of writing a temporary file that then exports what I need?

Comment: @DavidBoshton I've added some further examples above.

Comment: Suppose I want to export a function which depends on the es6 module. For example an es6 only react library. How would I do that ? Could my final react component function be asynchronous ?

Comment: @shellking4 I encourage you to post a question proper, preferably with some code.

Answer (score 7):

ESModules and CommonJS are mutually exclusive, so you can't "use ES6 modules inside CommonJS".

However, in a way, you can "use CommonJS inside ESModules", if by "CommonJS" you only mean the `require()` function. You can create an instance of `require()` function with [`module.createRequire()`](https://nodejs.org/api/module.html#modulecreaterequirefilename):

```js
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

// sibling-module.js is a CommonJS module.
const siblingModule = require('./sibling-module');
```

There's a chapter in NodeJS's documentation on [interoperability between the two module systems](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#interoperability-with-commonjs). It's very helpful, you might want to check it out.

Comment: You could however also simply `import './sibling-module';`, usually there's no reason to create a `require` function

Comment: That's true, but also kind of a given

Comment: This is no longer true. With the implementation of dynamic import in node you can now use ES modules in Commonjs by using the `import()` **function** (which returns a promise of the module) and the `import` syntax also now supports importing Commonjs modules

Comment: @slebetman Consider posting an answer, I'd be glad to read it

Comment: @slebetman "import syntax also now supports importing Commonjs modules" does the commonjs modules have to be with the extension ".cjs"?

Comment: @Archsx The documentation says "It can be used to load JavaScript CommonJS modules. Such modules are passed through the es-module-lexer to try to identify named exports, which are available if they can be determined through static analysis" -- so I think it can be either ".cjs" or ".js". However you should test to be sure. See: https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#modules-loaders

Comment: @slebetman, I've tried the example from [interoperability-with-commonjs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#interoperability-with-commonjs),and it works only with ".cjs" which seems to not mentioned in the doc, thx!

Comment: The question was about using es6 in CommonJs, not the other way around.