# Socket is not defined + other errors

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

Server side code:

```js
const http = require("http");
const host = 'localhost';
const port = 8000;
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

// creating the server and starting it on port 8000
const server = http.createServer();
server.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://${host}:${port}`);
});
// making io object
const io = new Server(server);


// listening to connections to the server
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
  });

// listening on port 8000
server.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log('listening on *:8000');
  });

// chat message coming to server

socket.on("details", (chatBundle) => {
    console.log(chatBundle);
});
```

Client side code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>CHAT ROOM</h1>
        <form onsubmit="return sendServer()">
            <label for="name">Name: 
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text">
            </label>
            
            <label for="text">Message: 
                <input id="text" name="text" type="text">
            </label>
            
            <input type="submit" id="send" >
        </form>
        <script src="/Users/chanson/node_modules/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            function sendServer(){
                var sender = document.getElementById("name");
                var text = document.getElementById("text");
                var tempArray = [sender, text]
                socket.emit(chatmsg, tempArray)
            };
        </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Aim: to make a chat messenger that would work on same computer browsers + ports. e.g. Firefox port user can communicate to Chrome, Edge, Opera and Safari. (please don't ask why I have so many browsers).

Comment: Which line of code is producing the error?

Comment: You'd better follow the official document, https://socket.io/get-started/chat

Comment: server.listen should be the last thing called after adding modules, routes and all that good stuff and it doesn't need calling twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Client side errors (3)

1. `chatmsg` has not been defined or given a value
2. `socket` has not been created or assigned to a variable
3. `sendServer` returns `undefined`, not `false` and hence will not prevent form submission when the submit button is pushed. (Calling `event.preventDefault` in the submit event is a more modern method of preventing submission).

A script element that addresses these considerations:

```js
<script>
    const chatmsg = "details"; // added
    const socket = io(); // added
    function sendServer(){
        var sender = document.getElementById("name");
        var text = document.getElementById("text");
        var tempArray = [sender, text]
        socket.emit(chatmsg, tempArray)
    return false; // added
    };
</script>
```

#### Server side errors (several)

1. **No application**.
   The client page must be served from the server in order to communicate with it using sockets -  CORS errors are generated if the client page is loaded using the `file://` protocol and then tries to communicate with the local host server using socket.io.

   1. A simple static express server can be set up to serve a request for `http://localhost:8000/client.html`.
   2. The server must also be capable of serving the socket.io client script using a suitable url in the `src` attribute of the client side script tag. A client tag used in testing was

      ```
      <script src="node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
      ```

      but will depend on server directory structure and possibly the version of `socket.io.js` in use.

   The app is supplied as an argument when creating the http server.
2. In the version of `socketIO` used for testing, requiring `socket.io` returns a function that is called to generate a socket server. Check documentation to verify that later versions return an export object with a `Socket` property. (See notes at bottom of answer)
3. **Socket message listening**
   This is in the wrong place - `socket` is an argument supplied to the `io.on("connection", handler)` handler function, and listening to socket events generated by the user who made the connection should be made in function scope of the connection handler.

---

#### Code used in testing

**client.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>CHAT ROOM</h1>
        <form onsubmit="return sendServer()">
            <label for="name">Name: 
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text">
            </label>
            
            <label for="text">Message: 
                <input id="text" name="text" type="text">
            </label>
            
            <input type="submit" id="send" >
        </form>
        <!-- <script src="/Users/chanson/node_modules/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.js"> -->
        <!-- particular to server setup: -->
        <script src="node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            const chatmsg = "details";
            var socket = io();
            function sendServer(){
                var sender = document.getElementById("name");
                var text = document.getElementById("text");
                var tempArray = [sender, text]
                socket.emit(chatmsg, tempArray)
                return false;
            };
        </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

**node script**

```js
const http = require("http");
const host = 'localhost';
const port = 8000;
 //** const { Server } = require("socket.io");
 //** 
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    app.use(express.static('./'));
 const socketIO = require("socket.io");
 

// creating the server and starting it on port 8000
//**const server = http.createServer();
   const server = http.createServer(app);


server.listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://${host}:${port}`);
});
// making io object

//**  const io = new Server(server);
    const io = socketIO(server, {cookie: false}); /* prevent io cookie - see https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2276 */


// listening to connections to the server
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    
//** move listening here, where socket is defined
    // chat message coming to server
    socket.on("details", (chatBundle) => {
           console.log(chatBundle);
    });
});
```

---

- The version of socket.io used to prepare this answer was 2.2.0.
- Version 4.x documentation confirms `socket` is still supplied to the connection handler.
- Version 4.x doco shows `Server` as being *imported* from the `socket.io` package, which can't be done in CommonJS packages because the don't support the `import` statement.
- AFAIK if in node you require an [ECMA module](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/esm.html) package from within a [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html) package, you are returned the default export of the ECMASScript module. You may need to investigate further if it is not the `Server` constructor function (or class object) exported in version 4.
- You can import ECMAScript modules in CommonJS using the `import` function (not keyword), but the import operation is asynchronous. See [How to use ES6 modules CommonJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70396400/5217142) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the way you import socket client please do something like

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

or CDN

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.5.4/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-/KNQL8Nu5gCHLqwqfQjA689Hhoqgi2S84SNUxC3roTe4EhJ9AfLkp8QiQcU8AMzI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

after that, you have to instantiate tour socket like:

```
const socket = io();
const text = document.getElementById("text")
socket.emit('chatMessage', text.value);
```

Make sure the event name is string ex here: `chatMessage`

Comment: I don't have the socket.io.js file there, so is there another way?

Comment: use CDN check my updated answer