# How to import rehype plugin in common js in webpack config

Tags: javascript, webpack, mdxjs, rehypejs, rehype

Unable to import `rehype-autolink-headings` in my webpack config (commonjs)
COde:

```js
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const rehype=require("rehype-autolink-headings") // <----- PROBLEM is HERE
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV == "production";

const stylesHandler = isProduction
  ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
  : "style-loader";


const config = {
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  devServer: {
    open: true,
    host: "localhost",
    historyApiFallback: true

  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "index.html",
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: "public", to: "./" },
      ],
    }),

    // Add your plugins here
    // Learn more about plugins from https://webpack.js.org/configuration/plugins/
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      // `js` and `jsx` files are parsed using `babel`
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
      },
      // `ts` and `tsx` files are parsed using `ts-loader`
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.mdx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: '@mdx-js/loader',
            /** @type {import('@mdx-js/loader').Options} */
            options: {
              rehypePlugins: [rehype],
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [stylesHandler, "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        type: "asset",
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".jsx", ".js", "..."],
  },
};

module.exports = () => {
  if (isProduction) {
    config.mode = "production";

    config.plugins.push(new MiniCssExtractPlugin());
  } else {
    config.mode = "development";
  }
  return config;
};
```

Getting this error:

```
[webpack-cli] Failed to load 'webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module node_modules\rehype-autolink-headings\index.js from webpack.config.js not supported.
```

My webpack versions:

```
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
```

How to make it work> I was trying a huge amount of approaches

Comment: It seems the library uses ES modules. So you can't directly require it instead you can use dynamic imports mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70396400/how-to-use-es6-modules-in-commonjs).

Comment: @Eldar I have tried it, no compile errors, but imported plugin does not work

Comment: Maybe this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903692/how-can-i-use-es6-in-webpack-config-js) can help. The only other option that comes into mind is to fork the plugin and compile it to commonjs and then publish it to npm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use native `esm` for `webpack` configuration cause it has been supported this for a while.

It means you need to fix your configuration a bit where to `require` and `export` your module and then rename the configuration file with `.mjs` extension to make sure `webpack` understands this is written in `esm` (`webpack.config.mjs`)

BTW, it's even better to write it in TS too which is addressed clearly how many languages that a configuration can be written [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-languages/)

Comment: Was trying TS approach without success ((

Comment: migrated to TS and was able to import rehype plugin, however, rehype plugin does not work ((