# Got an error when I tried to use the Openai SDK in Node.js

Tags: node.js, openai-api

I am trying to use Openai api with nodejs, I follow the tutorial and want to add a simple gpt text completion feauture using the openai SDK, but I got an error says: /node_modules/openai/core.js:44
const isJSON = contentType?.includes('application/json') || contentType?.includes('application/vnd.api+json');

It results in a crash of the app, I didn't find out why.

This is the code:

```js
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

export const gptResponse = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { message } = req.body;
        const getResponse = await openai.chat.completions.create({
            model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
            messages: [
                {
                    role: 'system',
                    content: 'You are a helpful assistant.',
                },
                {
                    role: 'user',
                    content: message,
                },
            ],
        });
        console.log(getResponse.data.choices[0].message.content);
        return res.json(getResponse.data.choices[0].message.content);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).send('Error. Try again.');
    }
};
```

Comment: When posting an error please post the entire error, formatted.

Comment: @DaveNewton The full error is this:
 const isJSON = contentType?.includes('application/json') || contentType?.includes('application/vnd.api+json');
                               ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)

Node.js v18.15.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work.

Save as `demo.js'

```js
import OpenAI from 'openai';

const openai = new OpenAI({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const requestData = {
    model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
    messages: [
        {
            role: 'system',
            content: 'You are a helpful assistant.',
        },
        {
            role: 'user',
            content: 'Hello!',
        },
    ],
};

async function getGPTResponse() {
    try {
        const response = await openai.chat.completions.create(requestData);
        console.log("Response from OpenAI:", response.choices[0].message.content);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error.message);
    }
}

getGPTResponse();
```

In package.json

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "openai": "^4.28.0"
  }
}
```

##### Install dependencies

```
npm install
```

##### Run it

```
node demo.js
```

##### Result

[image]

##### Confirm by Postman

You can see the response message's  hierarchy

url

```
POST https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions
```

In body

```json
{
    "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    "messages": [
      {
        "role": "system",
        "content": "You are a helpful assistant."
      },
      {
        "role": "user",
        "content": "Hello!"
      }
    ]
  }
```

[image]

[image]

---

##### insufficient permissions cases

##### #1 Read Only `API_KEY`

[image]

Error

```
Error: 401 You have insufficient permissions for this operation. Missing scopes: model.request
```

[image]

##### #2 Model capabilities Write `API_KEY`

[image]

No Error
[image]

##### #3 All Permissions `API_KEY`

[image]

No Error
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will try to find the issue, may be the token issue

Comment: The whole error message I got is this:
/Users/yelinliu/Documents/GitHub/moegpt-backend/node_modules/openai/core.js:44
    const isJSON = contentType?.includes('application/json') || contentType?.includes('application/vnd.api+json');
                               ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)

Node.js v18.15.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

I use the process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY to load the token, and I checked the quota, it's available.

Comment: @Lawrence, I updated three `API Key` permission cases and error message code is changed. I think you did call Inappropriate API Key. And my node version is v18.19.0 and `openai` version is 4.28.0

Comment: Hi, @Bench Vue ,I used the same API KEY and created a simple file outside this project and it worked. I found the reason for the app's crash from the first line when I imported the Openai module into this project, if I commented it out, the app would not crash. I think maybe it's because some packages I use may have issues with openai, I will keep on experimenting with this, thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to check "type": "module" is exisat in your package.json. It support `import` staement, if not you have to use require, please see this [es6-modules vs commonjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70396400/how-to-use-es6-modules-in-commonjs)

Comment: Yeah, I used the esm package to allow me to use import and require at the same time, it worked for other packages, I tried to use require for openai, the app crashed as I used import

Comment: Thanks, I am happy to hear got the root of the cause.

Comment: Thanks! The app still crashes. I will put the github repo link here: https://github.com/ProgrammingDojo/moegpt-backend
This error can be produced on the branch 2-server-side-chat-feature
Anyway, thank you so much for taking the time on this

Comment: I will look after return home, now I need to go to work.

Comment: @Lawrence, I looked it but it is backend source for user/chat gpt message. I don't see any relation with gptResponse().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256945/discussion-between-lawrence-and-bench-vue).

Comment: I added command in chat.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue is that openai SDK has some conflicts with the "esm" package, previously, I tried to use esm to allow using 'require' with 'import', and when I import 'openai', the app crashes instantly. After I removed the esm package and used 'require' for the whole app, this problem was solved.